# How to run or setup rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Have 2 ruby installations 1.8 and 1.9.1, have 2 gems. From "gem1.9.1 install rails" installed rails3 to my system, but don't have "rails" in my "path".

How can i get rails to launch from entering rails in terminal?

```
EDIT
```

removed all ruby and ruby-gems from my system (Ubuntu 10.10) and installed ruby1.9.1 - it came with gems1.9.1 and then installed

```
gem1.9.1 install rails
```

How do i make "rails" run the installed gem rails?

```
EDIT 2
```

Found it!

The rails was installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin/rails
just had to add a alias "rails" to it in system $PATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you install your rubies? I'd strongly suggest to use a version manager like [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/), otherwise you're asking for trouble.

Comment: i am using 10.10 and the standart repo, has rails 2.3... so i installed ruby1.9.1 and then ruby gems. But i had ruby1.8 on my system from the first try of installing rails

Comment: Please do not hesitate, and just install rvm.

Answer (score 1):

You should be specific about your system environment. In windows when you [install ruby](http://www.hashemzahran.com/riding-the-rails-installing-ruby-on-rails/), you just have RUBY_HOME/bin in your path. Whenever you install rails by `gem install rails` , it automatically deploy executable files in RUBY_HOME/bin folder. So that you can directly execute that command.